# Panda merge all columns start with a prefix "result"

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dynamic dataframe generation which create column or columns like below x,y,z, can be anything

df

```
   result  result_x  result_y  result_z  result_.....        
    0       1          1             0              
    0       1          0             1
```

some times it will generate

```
   result  result_x          
    0       1                      
    0       1
```

Some time it will generate

```
   result  result_x  result_y         
    0       1           1           
    0       1           2
```

some time it can generate

```
   result  result_x  result_y result_z result_a result_b......any number of result         
    0       1           1           
    0       1           2
```

I want a simple dataframe which will merge all columns start prefix with `result`

it would be output of first df:

```
result
0110.. #merge all columns value
0101...
```

**Note:**

I have other columns as well in df

like

```
username,address,xapi_data,...,result,result_x,result_y,...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.str.startswith`:

```
result_cols = df.columns.str.startswith('result')

(df.loc[:, result_cols]               # extract result columns
   .astype(str).agg(''.join, axis=1)  # join them
   .to_frame('result').join(df.loc[:, ~result_cols]) # join the other columns
)
```

Comment: I got error `ValueError: Item wrong length 12 instead of 3.`  I have other columns as well like username, directory, address

Comment: Updated the first approach.